# ASP.NET can't find controls in a repeater

Tags: asp.net, repeater, findcontrol

Repeater markup:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater_sorular" runat="server" OnItemCommand="Repeater_sorular_ItemCommand"
        OnItemDataBound="Repeater_sorular_ItemBound">
        <HeaderTemplate>
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <rad:RadChart ID="RadChart1" runat="server" DefaultType="Pie" Width="700">
                            <PlotArea Appearance-FillStyle-FillType="Gradient" Appearance-FillStyle-MainColor="#D90420"
                                Appearance-FillStyle-SecondColor="#FFAD4A" Appearance-Border-Visible="false">
                                <EmptySeriesMessage>
                                    <TextBlock Text="Seçilen anket henüz oylanmamıştır.">
                                        <Appearance TextProperties-Font="Tahoma, 10pt, style=Bold">
                                        </Appearance>
                                    </TextBlock>
                                </EmptySeriesMessage>
                            </PlotArea>
                            <ChartTitle>
                                <TextBlock Appearance-TextProperties-Font="Tahoma">
                                </TextBlock>
                            </ChartTitle>
                            <Appearance ImageQuality="HighQuality" Border-Color="#DFDDDD" TextQuality="ClearTypeGridFit">
                            </Appearance>
                            <Series>
                                <rad:ChartSeries Type="Pie" Appearance-TextAppearance-TextProperties-Color="#FFFFFF"
                                    Appearance-TextAppearance-TextProperties-Font="Tahoma">
                                </rad:ChartSeries>
                            </Series>
                            <Legend Visible="True">
                                <TextBlock Visible="True">
                                </TextBlock>
                            </Legend>
                        </rad:RadChart>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div style="font-weight: bolder; padding: 5px;">
                            <%#(((RepeaterItem)Container).ItemIndex+1).ToString() %>.
                            <%#Eval("Subject")%>
                        </div>
                        <asp:BulletedList ID="BulletedList_secenekler" runat="server" DataSource='<%#Eval("Secenekler")%>'
                            DataTextField="OptionName" DataValueField="OptionId" CssClass="sira_numarali">
                        </asp:BulletedList>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>
        </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

and repeater `ItemDataBoundEvent`:

```
protected void Repeater_sorular_ItemBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    RadChart RadChart1 = (RadChart)e.Item.FindControl("RadChart1");
    BulletedList bl = (BulletedList)e.Item.FindControl("BulletedList_secenekler");
}
```

When I debugged it controls return null. How can I fix it.

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried ClientIDMode="Static"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The method is called for each row you have, including the header. It's possible you are getting null the for the first row as the first one is the header (and it's empty). In order to solve it, you need to filter the method with

```
if(e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem) {
    //your code 
}
```

Comment: There are lot of things to learn about asp.net for me:) it works thanks.

Comment: your description is better than my question's answer :)

Comment: when I changes chart properties, All of charts changed. Can I get specific row item. or any  way??

Comment: for example control c = e.item(0).findcontrol(); c.text="whatever"; I mean something like that.

Comment: One dirty way is to do `if(e.Item.ItemIndex == 0) c.Text="whatever";`  in your ItemBound event